# possiblitiy of namespace clash between django app and a php site on the same wamp server

Tags: php, django, wamp, mod-wsgi

I have a running production server on a 64 bit windows os machine, using Wamp 2.2e (which uses Apache 2.4) with mod_wsgi 3.4 (an unofficial compile from pythonlibs) with python 2.7 64bit as well and Django 1.5. This is for a small closed company network so sadly I can't give out any actual links.

My wsgi alias looks like so:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /Taurus /www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
```

I have another site, built by a former employee which uses PHP. It's on an older server (I have access) and would like to move it over to mine. However, I'm afraid the urls between the php site and the django app would clash, because the php site is in a folder called Taurus (our Team's name).

In other words, I would like that when going here:

```
http://breezeblocks/Taurus/
```

The site will go to the php directory with the same name (and run index.php that is inside of it), but when going here:

```
http://breezeblocks/Taurus/Scheduler
```

It would go to the django app.

The '/' url is not in use inside urls.py so there's no actual duplication, but I'm guessing wamp can't figure that out and would just pick one of them.

Does anyone have a good idea how to set it up so it would both unclash and make sense? Should I maybe try to convert his entire site to django and have it as another app? Another idea I had was maybe give the wsgi alias a more direct name like:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /Taurus/scheduler /www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
```

But there's still a good possibility of a clash there. The site is running and in use so I'm afraid to go ahead with it without more information.

Thanks in advance for any help and input. Hope I made the question clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried what is outlined in:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive

The part at the end of that section explains how to use mod_rewrite so that if the PHP site is able to handle the URL it will, and if not, then the URL would be passed to Django to handle. This way they can coexist.

Comment: That sounds perfect! But I'm a bit confused about how to use mod_rewrite... could you show me an example how to use it in my case?

Comment: As I have absolutely no idea about the specifics of how you have Apache configured for your PHP site, not easily. The documentation should at least guide you and if you search on Google you can find various others sites which describe that specific mod_rewrite rule pattern.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it. I did not configure the php site at all but rather move the folder with index.php to the www directory (it works out of the box like that). I'm still not sure what I should do but you gave me the direction. Thanks!